# Getting up and running with Docker EE

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I have just installed Docker EE on my Windows 2016 server. (Following instructions at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/docker-ee/) and pulling volumes works and running containers has been fine.

But it feels limited.
Previously I’ve been using Docker on my Windows 10 PC using the Virtualbox based system. So I’m used to using Docker-Machine, SSH and Docker-Compose.
Are these available for use with Docker EE, or should we be looking to work differently?

I’m also unable to manage volumes as “docker volume ls” finds nothing, despite many volumes existing in the system.

It feels like it’s a limited install as it is. Should I be installing more? Or installing something like the Docker for Windows product instead/alongside?

Any basic tips are welcome.